# How do I add ajax call without changing my links in browser?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, struts

I have a site with couple of links on it. Now I want to make those link calls as an Ajax. The browser location work as previously. Also the back and forward button should works. Please suggest any framework that supports java/jsp/struts.

Comment: You going to have trouble with `back and forward button` with ajax.

Comment: use history api of html5 with jquery or go with angularjs/emberjs/knockoutjs.

Comment: HTML5 has been around for a while. 
Users running browsers that are too old to support HTML5 do not deserve rich functionality.